# При запросе страницы при помощи axios возвращается html страницы в виде нечитаемых символов

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
const getPage = (url, pathToSave = process.cwd()) => {
  if (url.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  // Паттерн, что это url, а не что-то ещё
  return axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    .then(({ data }) => fs.writeFile(`${pathToSave}/example.html`, data)
      .then(() => console.log('saved'))
      .catch(() => console.log('can\'t save html page')))
    .catch(() => console.log('can\'t get data from url'));
};
```

Функция которая запрашивает страницу и сохраняет её в виде html. При запросе через axios вместо html разметки я получаю нечитаемые символы, как буд-то сбита кодировка. Пробовал на разных сайтах, как результат одно и то же. В чём может быть дело?

Comment: У вас файл в какой кодировке? Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Сам файл со скриптом?

Comment: Да, именно он. Может он в кодировке cp-1251, вот кодировка и плывет... + посмотрите, в какой кодировке у вас сохраняются файлы.

Comment: Я создал его в vc code. Кодировка utf-8